# Android Applink url resolving conflicts error

Tags: android, applinks, android-deep-link, android-app-links

I added .well-known/assetlinks.json to my site and when I try link and verify in android studio app link assistant  it says "Success! Your app is associated with the selected domains." But when I test app links in android studio it says "URL resolving conflicts please link and verify your digital asset links". But in link and verify tab it says ok!

My application id is correct and I am trying on test apk on my mac and sha fingerprints is also correct.

what am i missing?

[image: verify result]

[image: test error]

Comment: Just check if it is working in actual phone?

Comment: It will work.  It happens sometimes.  If you again click verify,  it ll be success again

Comment: It works on phone like that asking open in chrome or app. Shouldn't it open the app directly? Is this behavior right ? @Zachary

Comment: Yes the behavior is right.  Select app

Comment: Okay but what the assetlinks.json work here. won't system ask same  only with intent filter  ?

Comment: You need to put that in the server side

Comment: Yeah İ put it on server but I wonder about if it works  without it only 
with intentt filter. İ will try it thanks a lot

Comment: Same issue but I get the message "This URL doesn’t map to any activity" when I click "Test app links".

Comment: Also I still see URL bar and not getting custom launch icon. Everything else is working.

Comment: Hi albo do you have intent filter with your host data

Comment: It wont work without asset links.json because your app is taking ownership of the domain. And the only way the android system knows about your ownership is through the asstlinks.json

Comment: I am having the same problem. Every check works up to the final test, but it asks to open in app or chrome. The point of of this verification is to make the app the default one for the link. Did you resolve your issue?

Comment: @nikinci were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

I get this error if the adb use libusb backend checkbox is not checked.
Go to Android Studio > User > Preferences... and on the left side menu click Build, Execution, Deployment. Then click Debugger. Under the title Android Debug Bridge check the use libusb backend checkbox and hit apply. Now retest the link.

Answer (score 1):

May be you are missing buildToolsVersion in .gradle file.
Also hit the link with your applink.json hosted domain name change in `https://digitalassetlinks.googleapis.com/v1/statements:list?source.web.site=<your-applink-hosted-domain>&relation=delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls`

Let me know if this fixes your issue.

Comment: Even this returns a valid statement for me. Yet a chooser/disambiguation dialog is shown when a valid applink url is clicked! What must be the reason?

Comment: I am also facing same issue. Success! Host www.******.com grants app deep linking to com.******.still chooser/disambiguation dialog is shown. please anyone help me out,

Answer (score 0):

Basically,  there is a problem in the App Link Assistant itself.  After successful link and verification process,  it shows this error once in a while.  But if you try again,  it will be success.  No need to worry.  Just test in the actual phone and it should work fine.